# Put for loops into a function

Tags: r

I have a list of for loops that I would like to embed in a function. However, the result given by this function is `NULL`. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6),
  id = rep(rep(1:2, each = 3), 2),
  foo = c(1998, 2000, 2004, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011)
)

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group    id   foo
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 A         1  1998
 2 A         1  2000
 3 A         1  2004
 4 A         2  1997
 5 A         2  1998
 6 A         2  1999
 7 B         1  2006
 8 B         1  2008
 9 B         1  2010
10 B         2  2009
11 B         2  2010
12 B         2  2011
```

I tried to adapt the following loop:

```
for (i in c("A", "B")){
  test <- test %>%
    mutate(
      foo = case_when(
        group == i & id == 1 ~ "foo_1",
        group == i & id == 2 ~ "foo_2",
        TRUE ~ as.character(foo)
      ))
}
test
```

with this function:

```
test_function <- function(x, y){
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)

  for (i in c("A", "B")){
    test <- test %>%
      mutate(
        !!x := case_when(
          group == i & (!!y) == 1 ~ "foo_1",
          group == i & (!!y) == 2 ~ "foo_2",
          TRUE ~ as.character(!!(x))
        ))
  }
}
```

But `test_function(foo, id)` returns something `NULL`.

Here's my expected output (I know it can be obtained without the loop but here I would like to know how to embed a loop in a function):

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   group    id   foo something
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 A         1  1998 foo_1    
 2 A         1  2000 foo_1    
 3 A         1  2004 foo_1    
 4 A         2  1997 foo_2    
 5 A         2  1998 foo_2    
 6 A         2  1999 foo_2    
 7 B         1  2006 foo_1    
 8 B         1  2008 foo_1    
 9 B         1  2010 foo_1    
10 B         2  2009 foo_2    
11 B         2  2010 foo_2    
12 B         2  2011 foo_2
```

How can I put this loop into a function? Note that I would like to put a lot of loops in a unique function.

Comment: Your non-function for loop returns the same error, does it not? At least it does for me. Make sure to fix the error in the code before turning it into a function.

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my post, the loop should work now but the function returns `NULL`

Comment: You need to return values from functions. Variables changed inside of functions don't exist outside of that function. If you add `return(test)` to the end of your function, it will return an updated data.frame after the transformations are complete. You can then choose to replace your original data.frame with that value if you like.

Comment: It works, thanks. Put it as an answer if you want